# How to get around the ADAL session timeout?

Tags: asp.net, azure, adal

I'm currently working on a LOB web application using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Azure ADAL. While the initial login works perfectly fine the problem that I keep facing is the session timeout which (I think) happens after 1 hour.

The first request to occur after that period of time will get redirected - to refresh the token AFAIK - and then redirected back to the application. This behavior is not a problem on synchronous GET requests but it can be a huge problem for asynchronous or POST requests. If a user is working on a form for 5 - 10 minutes it may easily happen that he is redirected and all input is simply lost.

I've read somewhere that an iframe with a simple periodic refresh would help but evidently it doesn't.

Am I missing something here? Is there really no way around this?